# Text::CSV supported encodings

Tags: csv, raku

Where can I find the encodings supported by Text::CSV? Is "latin1" not supported or is the syntax wrong?

This does fail:

```
use Text::CSV;

spurt '/tmp/test.csv', 'ID;Gerät;Nr', :enc<latin1>;

slurp '/tmp/test.csv', :enc<latin1>; #ok

say csv :in</tmp/test.csv>, :encoding<latin1>, :sep_char<;>; 
#Malformed UTF-8 error
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's doing anything with the encoding parameter. This is where it opens the file https://github.com/Tux/CSV/blob/master/lib/Text/CSV.pm#L1694

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There was an error in the code: the encoding declared was not actually used when opening the file. I created an issue in the module, and [this pull request to fix it](https://github.com/Tux/CSV/pull/15)

Answer (score 6):

It looks like the documentation for `Text::CSV` requires that [the value passed to `encoding` must be the same as that accepted by the `open` function's `encoding` parameter](https://modules.perl6.org/dist/Text::CSV:cpan:HMBRAND/lib/Text/CSV.pod6#L1856).

The list of possible values is listed in the [`IO::Handle::encoding` method documentation](https://docs.perl6.org/type/IO::Handle#method_encoding):

> The accepted values for encoding are case-insensitive. The available encodings vary by implementation and backend. On Rakudo MoarVM the following are supported:
>
> - `utf8`
> - `utf16`
> - `utf16le`
> - `utf16be`
> - `utf8-c8`
> - `iso-8859-1`
> - `windows-1251`
> - `windows-1252`
> - `windows-932`
> - `ascii`
>
> The default encoding is `utf8`, which undergoes normalization into Unicode NFC (normalization form canonical). In some cases you may want to ensure no normalization is done; for this you can use `utf8-c8`. Before using `utf8-c8` please read Unicode: Filehandles and I/O for more information on `utf8-c8` and NFC.
>
> As of Rakudo 2018.04 `windows-932` is also supported which is a variant of ShiftJIS.
>
> Implementation may choose to also provide support for aliases, e.g. Rakudo allows aliases `latin-1` for `iso-8859-1` encoding and dashed utf versions: `utf-8` and `utf-16`.

Comment: open handles latin1: `my $io =  open '/tmp/test.csv', :r, :enc<latin1>;`
`say Text::CSV.new.getline_all: $io; #Ok`

Comment: @ValleLukas It's disconcerting it works for `latin1`. The above doc only mentions `latin-1`.

Comment: @raiph latin-1 is only an example for implemented aliases in rakudo. [Internals.pm6](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/7aa72ce0965b518a6ac09ef8e3e1a29be78194cf/src/core/Rakudo/Internals.pm6) lists many more (line 280ff).

Comment: Ah. Great. Thanks.

Comment: This was all I could find in the perl6 documentation. Additional functionality may be provided depending on the implementation and not documented well. The question asked for a list of supported encodings, and this was the best I could find. If anyone else can find more, please update this answer accordingly. Thanks!